# Great Grails opensource application I could learn from

Tags: open-source, grails, groovy, system

I love to learn new and better ways to program from good opensource applications written in desired language/using such technology. Now I am digging into Grails and I didn't succeded in searching great and usable opensource application written in Grails. I tried googlecode, github and even the community page on grails documentation webpage. Find nothing really top quality application (missing documentation, too simple and so on). Maybe I missed some, but maybe users of grails have their loved famous app. Could someone recommend me any?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of open source projects based on Grails here: http://www.grails.org/OpenSource+Projects

Comment: Thank you. Well I tried about half of that, but I wasn't sure if I found some good examples. And because of that I am asking if someone has good exprerience with some OS system.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best is Graeme Rocher's Building Twitter in 40 minutes demo.
http://www.springsource.com/webinar/building-twitter-with-grails-40-minutes

Comment: Looks great, thank you. Unfortunately I can't download more than three MB.

Comment: Isak Rickyanto and myself used to host pages with this stuff. I lost mine when twitblogs stopped working suddenly. Isak used to host grailsdeveloper.com. Off the top of my head the two post memorable other ones were Sven Haiges [GroovyTweets][1] (It had GAE/Twitter stuff) and Glen Smith's [Groovyblogs][2] (It was a blog aggregator & used Glassfish at one point). You might want to check out the [Grailspodcast][3] too. [1]: https://github.com/hansamann/groovytweets/archives/master [2]: http://code.google.com/p/groovyblogs/ [3]: http://grailspodcast.com/

Comment: Someone else did a family tree project in Grails too. I think it was the guy who wrote the Drools plugins.. [Famree][1] [1]: http://manoharviswanathan.com/blog/tech/introducing-famree/

Comment: I can also highly recommend [Dave Klein's][1] book as a way to learn the essentials of Grails fast. [1]:http://www.amazon.co.uk/review/R3QZC89SLVAGGE/ref=cm_cr_pr_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1934356468&nodeID=&tag=&linkCode=

Comment: Of course there is also [Groovymag][1]  [1]: http://groovymag.com/

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/grails/grails-samples